# How to solve/what is the best way to approach it?

Tags: python, matrix, physics

I have confusion/difficulties related to this code: the code didn't print out anything yet there is no error message. The context is, I want to change some components of the main random matrix (`psi`) to the new matrix (`psiy`) and I want to check whether my code is correctly with regard to the component's index (hence the `print(init,sy)`) but nothing comes out and no error message either. Anyone has any idea? Thank you very much in advance.

The full problem is here:

I have a 3D matrix (nx X ny X nz), with `nx` being the number of components in the x-axis (say, horizontal), `ny` being the number of components in the y-axis (say, vertical), and `nz` being the number of component in the z-axis (say, out of the plane). So the total of components is `A`. We can also see it as a 2x2 matrix with many layers (`nz` total of layers). The index of each component started from the top left of the first layer to the bottom right of the `z-th` layer.

So for a `4x4x4` matrix, we will have `0 to 63` indexes with `0 to 15` in the first layer, `16 to 31` in the second layer, and so on. And for the first layer, since `nx` and `ny` is `4`, there are a total of `4` indexes in each row and column (`0 to 3` for the first row, `4 to 7` for the second row, and `12 to 15` for the fourth row), the same order for the other layers.

I want to change my initial random matrix `psi` to a new matrix `psiy` with these conditions:

1. The `init`-th components of the new matrix `psiy` will be the `init`-h components of the old matrix `psi` times `3`
2. The `sy`-th components of the new matrix `psiy` will be the `sy`-th components of the old matrix `psi`

Now, how do we know what are the `init` and `sy` components? We go back to the description of components of my 3D matrix, if we group it with respect to the column, for the first layer (index `0 to 15`), there are `4` columns since `ny` is `4` and what I mean by `init` is the top index of the column, in this case the `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3` indexes. So for the second layer init would be `16`, `17`, `18`, and `19` indexes and so on for the rest of the layers.

While for `sy`, the definition is all the indexes in the even-th rows except for the last row. So for the case of `nx`, `ny` and `nz` is `4`, `sy` indexes would be:

`4 to 7` for the first layer (since there are only 4 rows (nx) and the only even-th row is the `2nd` row (not including the last row)), and

`20 to 23` for the second layer, `36 to 39` for the third layer, and `52 to 55` for the last layer.

So for `ny` is for example `8`, the `sy` would be all the indexes in the 2nd, 4th, and 6th rows in each layer and so on for any (even) number of `ny`.

Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
nx=4
ny=4
nz=4
A=nx*ny*nz

HH=ny-2
H=int(HH/2)
psiy=np.zeros(A)
psi=np.random.randint(1,10,nx)

for i in range (0,nz):
    for m in range (1,H):
        for k in range (0,nx):
            init=i*nx*ny+k
            sy=init+(2*m-1)*nx
            psiy[init]=3*psi[init]
            psiy[sy]=1*psi[sy]
            print(init,sy)
```

Comment: H is 1, so this loop won't execute at all:
for m in range (1,H):

Comment: This is the kind of debugging problem that can be solved with a bunch of print statements. Add print statements to show the value of your variables at various points, and make sure they're what you expect. A debugger would work even better, if you're willing to learn to use it, but print-debugging requires nothing more than print statements. If I was debugging this myself and really couldn't figure out what was going on, I might end up with print statements all over that code! Once it works, delete them all.